# get all atributes from xmltable using xquery

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery

I have an xml table where each item has a lot of attributes

For example,

```
DIG_POINT LowValue="2" StatusText1="LIG 21" StatusText2="LIG 22" StatusText3="LIG 23"
```

All the examples I have seen always have to refer the columns names

```
 SELECT xmlkey , x.*
     FROM xmlimport t,
          XMLTABLE ('/SRDBSW/DIG_POINT[@LowValue="2"]' PASSING t.XMLDATA COLUMNS StatusText1 VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@StatusText1') x
    WHERE xmlkey = 'TEST';
```

My problem is that attributes names may be added dynamically.

Is there a way to get something like "select * from .... ", where it is possible to get all attributes from each item?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an XPath to extract the attributes, and convert each one to an name/value pair in a dummy element:

```
SELECT t.xmlkey, x.*
FROM xmlimport t
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE ('for $i in /SRDBSW/DIG_POINT[@LowValue="2"], $j in $i/@*
  return element tmp { attribute name {local-name($j)}, attribute value {$j} }'
  PASSING t.XMLDATA
  COLUMNS
    attr_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH '/tmp/@name',
    attr_value VARCHAR2(30) PATH '/tmp/@value'
) x
WHERE t.xmlkey = 'TEST';

XMLK ATTR_NAME                      ATTR_VALUE                   
---- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
TEST LowValue                       2                             
TEST StatusText1                    LIG 21                        
TEST StatusText2                    LIG 22                        
TEST StatusText3                    LIG 23
```

The `for $i in ...` gets all the matching nodes, as you were already doing; then within that `for $j in $i/@*` gets all the attributes for that node. The `element` constructs a new node, and the `attribute` clauses convert the attribute name (from `local-name()`) and the actual attribute value into separate named attributes in that dummy element. The `path` can then refer to the known attributes names in the dummy element.

You don't actually need both `$i` and `$j`, it just shows what is happening a bit more clearly; you can have your XPath like this if you prefer:

```
'for $i in /SRDBSW/DIG_POINT[@LowValue="2"]/@*
  return element tmp { attribute name {local-name($i)}, attribute value {$i} }'
```

Or even simpler, move the `local-name()` look-up into the `path`:

```
SELECT t.xmlkey, x.*
FROM xmlimport t
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE ('/SRDBSW/DIG_POINT[@LowValue="2"]/@*'
  PASSING t.XMLDATA
  COLUMNS
    attr_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'local-name(.)',
    attr_value VARCHAR2(30) PATH '.'
) x
WHERE t.xmlkey = 'TEST';

XMLK ATTR_NAME                      ATTR_VALUE                   
---- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
TEST LowValue                       2                             
TEST StatusText1                    LIG 21                        
TEST StatusText2                    LIG 22                        
TEST StatusText3                    LIG 23
```

Comment: THANK VERY MUCH , THANK YOU , fI you let me ask just one question , since I have lot´s of different "items" liike DIG_POINT , is possible to "EXTRACT" the name if the node -->"item" ?

Comment: @AntónioRoque : Don't forget to accept that answer that bests answers your question. The reputation points earned give people the incentive to continue answering questions. Good luck to all.

Comment: how ? ... I´m new sorry , How I do that ?